# Trouble in parsing date using dateutil - day and year

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I use python dateutil to parse string to date:

```
parse(' 19     2015  '.strip(), fuzzy=True)
```

But this throws an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:/BitNami_Djangostack/django_mongo_test/glr_test/example.py", line 179, in <module>
    print('parse(month_to_eng_replace', parse(' 19     2015  ', fuzzy=True))
  File "M:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.py", line 743, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "M:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.py", line 310, in parse
    ret = default.replace(**repl)
ValueError: month must be in 1..12
```

In other answer on stackoverflow i read that option `fuzzy=True` ignores uknown tokens, but how do i explain that 19 is day, not month number, and i provide only two: day and year?
option `dayfirst=True` not working for this.

Comment: You should take a look at http://strftime.org/, you can specify what should be parsed as a day and what should be parsed as a year using it.

Comment: Is that..day of the year?  Or day of the current month? Can you just use the standard `time.strptime` function (or the `datetime` equivalent)?

Comment: what is the month supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the month just add a month that has 31 days and concat that to the start:

```
from dateutil import parser
dte = ' 9     2015  '
d = parser.parse("08" + dte)
```

Or just use datetime and split the string:

```
dte = ' 19     2015  '

from datetime import datetime
day, year = dte.split()
dte = datetime(day=int(day),year=int(year),month=8)
print(dte)
```

If you might have a month as commented and it will always be the second part of the string, you can either use that month or use a default value:

```
from datetime import datetime


def parse(s, month=8):
    data = s.split()
    return datetime(day=int(data[0]), year=int(data[-1]),
                    month=int(data[-2] if len(data) == 3 else month))
```

It will work for any string with either d-m-y or d-y:

```
In [10]: parse("    19    07     2015   ")
Out[10]: datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 19, 0, 0)

In [11]: parse("   19   2015   ")
Out[11]: datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 19, 0, 0)
```

`data[-2]` will get the second subelement if we have three substrings after splitting, `data[0]` will get the first and `data[-1]` will get the last so if the length is not 3 after splitting we only take the first and last elements and use a default value month or we use all three is the length of data is 3.

Comment: this might be correct, but i produce a lot of strings in loop, so i don't know where month is present, and where not. so i need some kind of default current month, but only if it not present in processed string.

Comment: will the month always be in the same place if it is there?

Comment: I assume in my case the same place - second, after day

Comment: This is correct, but i m trying to solve more complex problem: to deal with different mess in date data (you func works with len=2 and 3, but not with 4), for this i use http://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parser.html  - and now i need to add additional functionality to this lib. So i prefer to rewrite you function to return string (not datetime) and then pass this string to dateutil parse.

Comment: lot of formats - i even dont know all kinds of mess that produce sites, + encoding problems, month may be with characters &#x280 devided with spaces, so there are 5 or 10 items after split